# Javascript SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL when trying to use emoji's UTF code

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8, emoji

I wanted to add emoji to my string as UTF-8 code:

```
var c11 = new Road('/hl','\u{1F1F3-1F1F1} netherlands', node4);
```

According to [link](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f1f3_1f1f1), It is Netherlands flags emoji UTF-8 code. When I started my javascript app it throws me this error:

```
var c11 = new Road('/hl', '\u{1F1F3-1F1F1} netherlands', node4);
                     ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
```

When I write other emojis which has no dash symbol (for example `\u{1F338}`) it works nice. Why I can't use flags?

Comment: `'\u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F1} netherlands'` works for me. Flag emoji actually consist of two codepoints each (as the linked-to page shows), in this case U+1F1F3 (REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER N) and U+1F1F1 (REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER L).

Comment: @Biffen LOOOOL. This makes me look so inadequate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `\u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F1}` instead of `\u{1F1F3-1F1F1}`.